# Como consultar uma tabela de forma limitada (parcial)?

Tags: sql, query

Preciso consultar uma tabela extraindo dela as infos: `<nome>` e `<pontuacao>`, meu tcc consiste num jogo em que uma de suas opções é ver um Ranking de jogadores cadastrados. como existe a possibilidade do soft crescer em numero de usuários essa consulta poderá se tornar muito pesada se for retornar todas as tuplas da  tabela.

O que eu desejo é conseguir recuperar a posição do jogador corrente e 5 posições acima e 5 abaixo pra aliviar a carga.

O que eu consegui fazer foi:

```
select nome,pontuacao from jogador order by pontuacao DESC;
```

que faz a busca da tabela toda e isso pode prejudicar o sistema mais a frente.

Alguém saberia como limitar essa consulta?

Comment: Luis, qual SGBD você usa? Sql Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc?

Comment: Se for possível mudar a regra de negócio (_mostrar a posição do jogador, mais as 5 posições superiores e 5 inferiores_), eu aconselharia a trazer apenas um **Top10** através do uso da sintaxe `top()` do `SQL`, mais um `union` para retornar a posição atual do jogador.

Comment: Vou aplicar em MySQL.

Comment: luiz, vi o seu comentario apenas agora, infelizmente o MySQL é bem limitado quanto a recursos, você até poderia até tentar aproveitar a minha resposta e usar subqueries no lugar de CTE e emular o ROW_NUMBER, mas o desempenho não seria muito animador, outra possibilidade é cogitar o uso do PostgreSQL no lugar do MySQL.

Comment: Como ficaria essa consulta pronta no PostgreSQL ???Se for bom assim pode valer a pena trocar ... mudaria algo???

Comment: Talvez teria que fazer umas poucas modificações, mas a lógica seria a mesma. Qualquer coisa poste uma nova pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o top do SQL. Nesse caso você pode filtrar pela pontuação. Por exemplo: "select TOP(5) nome, pontuacao from jogador where pontuacao order by pontuacao >  DESC;". Caso a consulta seja a primeira a "ultima pontuacao consultada" será 0, caso contrário como o nome diz será a "ultima pontuacao consultada".

Veja: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp

Answer (score 0):

Se o SGBD em questão for o `Oracle`, o `Sql Server` ou o `PostgreSQL`, você pode usar uma `CTE` com `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH cte_rank AS (
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY pontuacao DESC) AS pos_rank,
        nome,
        pontuacao 
    from jogador
), cte_meu_rank AS (
    SELECT pos_rank
    FROM cte_rank
    WHERE nome = :nome
)

select 
    cte_rank.pos_rank,
    cte_rank.nome,
    cte_rank.pontuacao
FROM cte_meu_rank, cte_rank
WHERE cte_rank.pos_rank between cte_meu_rank.pos_rank - 5 AND cte_meu_rank.pos_rank + 5
```

onde `:nome` é uma variavel que recebe o nome do jogador atual.